# How can I style a control to go past browser window bounds like the HTML Select tag?

Tags: html, css

I noticed that when an HTML Select is stuck in a small window it will actually exit the browser and be displayed outside of it.

I have been looking everywhere to try and find out how this styling is applied and if I can assign the styles to my own custom controls.

If anybody has any know-how or information on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is an image of a select box exceeding the bounds of a browser window.
[image: Select Box Image]
Image apparently won't display and imgur won't let me upload, here is a link to the image. https://ibb.co/cwt2ke

I am running the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: example example example !!!

Comment: which browser are you taking about here ?

Comment: @G-Cyr, I have included an image of the behaviour I am looking for and specified my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Having any content displayed outside of your browser window, with modern standards, is impossible. Perhaps on older browser versions, this is possible, but not with modern browsers/browser versions. Using CSS to adjust content overflow would be your best bet, with content flowing past the visual boundaries of your browser window.

Comment: Also, for a browser window getting smaller, you can use media queries to adjust things based on window size.

Comment: I assumed the same thing until I saw how the HTML select box behaves; I'm assuming there is no simple solution to this. I'm more or less wondering if anybody knows how the HTML Select box is styled to have this type of behaviour and if it is possible to recreate it via CSS.

Comment: It doesn't seem impossible, the HTML select box has the exact behaviour I am inquiring about. I have edited to include an image of it. 

Unfortunately content overflow is only effective within a window and I am trying to eliminate scrollbars due to the fact that they affect some required static styles we have on our platform.

We do use media queries, unfortunately they are not a solution to this issue.

Comment: @RegSmith I do hope you find a solution, but from what I know and what I saw when researching, everyone said it was impossible. I can try to find it again, but I found a long thread on this exact subject and not one person said it was possible.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'll have to keep researching myself and see how the native HTML5 controls do it and if that type of support will be coming up in a future release.

Comment: @RegSmith I’ll be sure to let you know if I find anything, as I am intrigued to say the least, I shall keep researching the subject.